# Loss history for MLPRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using an MLPRegressor to solve a problem and would like to plot the loss function, i.e., by how much the loss decreases in each training epoch. However, the attribute `model.loss_` available for the MLPRegressor only allows access to the last loss value. Is there any possibility to access the whole loss history?

Comment: I am also interested on this, have you figured it out?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I just did it manually setting verbose = True and copying the output..

Comment: I see, I ended up doing the same

Answer (score 4):

Very simple actually: `model.loss_curve_` gives you the values of the loss for each epoch. You can then easily plot the learning curve by putting the epochs on the x axis and the values mentioned above on the y axis

Comment: Please add some detail as to how to use the code snippet above in order to improve your answer.

Comment: Note that this only works for the default `'adam'` solver.  No `model.loss_curve_` is produced with `'sgd'` or `'lbfgs'` solvers.  Took me a while to figure that out!

Answer (score 3):

As @francesco suggested, Very simple to use `model.loss_curve_` and plot these values as the y-axis and the index or epoch number as the x-asis.

**Sample code to plot the loss of a model trained with sci-kit learn:**

*Last line is the important one!*

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

# Create Neural Net MLP regressor 
# Explore settings logarithmically (0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.00001)
model = MLPRegressor(
    # try some layer & node sizes
    hidden_layer_sizes=(5,17), 
    # find a learning rate?
    learning_rate_init=.001,
    # activation functions (relu, tanh, identity)
    activation='relu',
    max_iter=2000
);

# Train it (where X_train is your feature matrix & Y_train is a vector with desired target values for each record)
nn_regr.fit(X_train,Y_train)

# Plot the 'loss_curve_' protery on model to see how well we are learning over the iterations
# Use Pandas built in plot method on DataFrame to creat plot in one line of code
pd.DataFrame(model.loss_curve_).plot()
```

[Model Loss Curve Plot using Pandas/Matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4qB6.png)

**To see this code in context, check out the Jupyter notebook**
https://github.com/atomantic/ml_class/blob/master/06%20-%20Regression%20Examples.ipynb
from an intro to ML workshop [@atomantic](https://github.com/atomantic) and [@jasonlewismedia](https://github.com/jasonlewismedia) put together.

Comment: Note that this only works for the default `'adam'` solver.  No `model.loss_curve_` is produced with `'sgd'` or `'lbfgs'` solvers.  Took me a while to figure that out!