# Training and validation loss history for MLPRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using an MLPRegressor to solve a problem and would like to plot the loss function for training and validation, i.e., by how much the loss decreases in each training epoch.

Here is the model:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_scaled[1:6000], y[1:6000], train_size=0.5, test_size=0.25)

mlp = neural_network.MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 20), activation="relu",
                 solver='adam', alpha=0.0001,
                 batch_size='auto', learning_rate="constant",
                 learning_rate_init=0.001,
                 max_iter=1000,tol=1e-4)

mlp.fit(x_train, y_train)
r = mlp.score(x_train, y_train)
y_predict = mlp.predict(x_test)
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45488558/loss-history-for-mlpregressor), I can plot the validation loss using the line:

```
test_validate1(x_test=x_test, y_test=y_test, y_predict=y_predict, classifier=mlp)
```

Yet, this only plots one curve, the validation loss. I want to diagnose how well the neural network worked by plotting training loss also and comparing the loss curves. Is there a way to extract this from my code?

Additionally, what are the units for loss?

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement this yourself.

**TL;DR**:

- Training loss is saved in the `reg.loss_curve_` attribute
- There's an [open request to add validation loss](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18507), but MLP modules are [unlikely to get new features](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18507#issuecomment-702717786)
- A solution may exist in the future [when the Callback API is stable](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/22000)

### Implementing for `MLPClassifier`

If you want to plot train/validation loss curves for `MLPClassifier`, you can split data into train/validation/test sets, perform `.partial_fit()` on batches, and estimate  the `log_loss` on the validation fold:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss

# Simulate train / test / validation sets
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000)
X_train, X_hold, y_train, y_hold = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=.6)
X_valid, X_test, y_valid, y_test = train_test_split(X_hold, y_hold, train_size=.5)

# Initialize
clf = MLPClassifier()
batch_size, train_loss_, valid_loss_ = 50, [], []

# Training Loop
for _ in range(50):
    for b in range(batch_size, len(y_train), batch_size):
        X_batch, y_batch = X_train[b-batch_size:b], y_train[b-batch_size:b]
        clf.partial_fit(X_batch, y_batch, classes=[0, 1])
        train_loss_.append(clf.loss_)
        valid_loss_.append(log_loss(y_valid, clf.predict_proba(X_valid)))

plt.plot(range(len(train_loss_)), train_loss_, label="train loss")
plt.plot(range(len(train_loss_)), valid_loss_, label="validation loss")
plt.legend()
```

[image: Line plot showing training and validation loss history. The training loss steadily decreases, whereas the validation loss starts increasing after 200 steps.]

---

### Implementing for `MLPRegressor`

The steps for creating the training and validation curves in `MLPRegressor` are similar, but now the loss function is computed with `mean_squared_error / 2`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Simulate train / test / validation sets
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1000)
X_train, X_hold, y_train, y_hold = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=.6)
X_valid, X_test, y_valid, y_test = train_test_split(X_hold, y_hold, train_size=.5)

reg = MLPRegressor()
batch_size, train_loss_, valid_loss_ = 50, [], []

for _ in range(150):
    for b in range(batch_size, len(y_train), batch_size):
        X_batch, y_batch = X_train[b-batch_size:b], y_train[b-batch_size:b]
        reg.partial_fit(X_batch, y_batch)
        train_loss_.append(reg.loss_)
        valid_loss_.append(mean_squared_error(y_valid, reg.predict(X_valid) / 2))

plt.plot(range(len(train_loss_)), train_loss_, label="train loss")
plt.plot(range(len(train_loss_)), valid_loss_, label="validation loss")
plt.legend()
```

[image: Line plot showing training and validation loss history for regression. Both steadily decrease until converging.]

---

### Footnotes

Technically these contain a small mistake. The `loss_` attribute of the neural network is the loss *before* weights are updated with `partial_fit()`. This means you'll see small differences if you explicitly compute the loss on each batch.

i.e., we should be doing the following, but this makes the training loop inconvenient to write, and it should not make a large difference in practice:

```py
valid_loss_.append(mean_squared_error(y_valid, reg.predict(X_valid) / 2))
reg.partial_fit(X_batch, y_batch)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a way.

You can just create two numpy arrays with the information of both train and validation loss and plot two lines in the same graph as in:

[Plotting multiple line graphs in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70937689/plotting-multiple-line-graphs-in-matplotlib)

Comment: That was my immediate thought, but I do not know how to grab the training info from the MLPRegressor object?

Comment: `loss_curve_` is the training info if you are using training data. If you give x_valid and y_valid, the loss will be related to the validation data.

Comment: What do you mean x_valid and y_valid?

Comment: x_valid is the input validation data. y_valid the output validation data.

Comment: Perhaps my question is not clear. I have edited my question with more info about my code. How would I, in practice, get the x_valid and y_valid needed for the loss curve?