# how to print mse vs epoch in MLPClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mlp

Hi everyone i have problem to print my result using MLPClassifier sklearn, i want my result is plot graphs mse vs epoch for training vs testing and this is my code :

```
#Spliting data into Feature and
x=Dt[['new_tests','people_vaccinated','people_fully_vaccinated','total_boosters','new_vaccinations']]
y=Dt[['new_cases','new_deaths']]

#Import train_test_split function**

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#Split dataset into training set and test set to be 70% and 30%
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)


# Import MLPClassifer and mse
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Create model object
flc = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(15,10),
                    random_state=5,
                    verbose=True,
                    max_iter=50,
                    learning_rate_init=0.1)

mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, ypred, squared=False)

# Fit data onto the model
flc.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Make prediction on test dataset
ypred = flc.predict(x_test)

# Import accuracy score 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# Calcuate accuracy
accuracy_score(y_test,ypred)
```

I was expecting the graph display mse vs epoch for training and testing Please, is anyone able to run it? Any ideas or suggestion? What could be causing this issue?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Mean square error is a regression metric. To visualize the loss per iteration, you can plot the `clf.loss_curve_`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification()

clf = MLPClassifier(max_iter=50).fit(X, y)

plt.plot(clf.loss_curve_)
plt.show()
```

If you want to plot something more complicated (e.g. error vs. epoch for training and testing), you'll to write a training loop like this: [Training and validation loss history for MLPRegressor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74631843/training-and-validation-loss-history-for-mlpregressor/74868477#74868477)