# why different loss formulas produce different values applied on the same model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network

I have to implement a Multi-layer perceptron model with the following data:

```
hl_parameters = {'hidden_layer_sizes': [(10,), (50,), (10,10,), (50,50,)]}

mlp_cv = MLPClassifier(max_iter=300, alpha=1e-4, solver='sgd', tol=1e-4, learning_rate_init=.1, verbose=True, random_state=ID)
mlp_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf = GridSearchCV(mlp_cv, hl_parameters, cv=5)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(clf.best_params_)
print(clf.best_score_)
```

And I obtain this output:

```
Best parameters set found: {'hidden_layer_sizes': (50,)} 
Score with best parameters:
0.7779999999999999
```

Now I assign mlp the value of `clf.best_estimator`. This should be equal to assign mlp the value of `MLPClassifier(hl_parameters.get('hidden_layer_sizes')[1], ...)` isn't it?

In order to calculate the training error and the test error, I've performed some loss formulas as you can read below.

The question is: why I obtain different values?
Which one should I consider?

```
mlp = clf.best_estimator_

y_trainpred= clf.predict(X_train)
training_error = np.mean(np.square(np.array(y_trainpred)-np.array(y_train)))
y_testpred= clf.predict(X_test)
test_error = np.mean(np.square(np.array(y_testpred)-np.array(y_test)))

print ("Best NN training error: %f" % training_error)
print('Best NN training error2: ', 1. - clf.best_score_)
print('Best NN training error3: ', 1. - mlp.score(X_train,y_train))
print('Best NN test error2: ', 1. - mlp.score(X_test,y_test))
print ("Best NN test error: %f" % test_error)
```

And I obtain this output:

```
Best NN training error: 0.000000
Best NN training error2:  0.2220000000000001
Best NN training error3:  0.0
Best NN test error2:  0.21289075630252097
Best NN test error: 2.588303
```

Answer (score 2):

> Which one should I consider?

The test set score estimates how your model performs on new data:

```py
>>> mlp.score(X_test, y_test)               # Instead of 1 - score()
0.7871092
```

[mlp.score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.score) tells you that the classifier is ~78% accurate. This should be close to `clf.best_score_`—the cross-validation score from `GridSearchCV`, and here they are within ~1% of each other.

---

The rest have different interpretations.

1. This line compares the mean squared error for a classification problem. This is not usually correct, since it applies a *regression* metric on a *classification* problem.

```py
test_error = np.mean(np.square(np.array(y_testpred)-np.array(y_test)))
```

2. There is a similar issue when evaluating mean squared error on the training set. However, neural networks are "[strong learners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_(machine_learning))" which can perfectly fit the training set so long as there are no labeling discrepancies. So any divergence metric on the training set should be driven to `0.0`:

```py
training_error = np.mean(np.square(np.array(y_trainpred)-np.array(y_train)))
```

For classification, the default loss function is "log loss." I wrote an answer here that better explains how to compute this for MLP classifiers and regressors: [Training and validation loss history for MLPRegressor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74631843/training-and-validation-loss-history-for-mlpregressor/74868477#74868477)

Comment: Thanks for answering me. But why If I run mlp.score(X_train,y_train) the results is 1.0 and the clf.bestscore is 0.7779999999999999. They should be equal, isn't it?

Comment: `clf.best_score_` is cross-validation error, so it represents the average error when sequentially splitting data, training on part, and evaluating performance on the rest. `mlp.score(X_train, y_train)` is measuring performance on the training set.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes it means that if the mlp.score(...) is 1.0, the model is 100% accurate and does not fail any input? I don't think it is possible in any model

Comment: @LudovicoLatini "*On the training set*" is the key phrase. Memorizing the training set will lead to 100% accuracy on the training set, but does not guarantee good performance on new data. Fully-expanded decision trees might be more intuitive.

Comment: Ok so if someone ask me the training error I can show them 1. - mlp.score(X_train, y_train)?

Comment: Sure! (Sorry to beleaguer this point, but again: training error tends not to be very informative, many models can achieve 0% error on the training set. It should compliment other metrics, reporting training error alone is misleading.)